# Overlapping two textures on one object

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, uv

I have one object with texture one it. I would like to mix another texture but only on some parts of the objecs.
Similar what painter does with the brush. He brushes smaller color parts into bigger background.

I hope I explained it. I can visualize it but don't know how to achieve it.

For example I would like that some smaller part of the object has another texture which fits into the brick texture as if it's eroded or torn down.

[image]

Comment: Please add screenshots to your question to help clarify your question. It's hard to provide help from a brief explanation, pictures/GIFs help a lot.

Comment: I hope this image helps.

Comment: Have you tried using an image texture or vertex paint as input to stencil between two shaders? Adding a mix shader between two different shaders can help, and you can plug the vertex color into the mix factor with an attribute node using the name of the vertex color layer. Same can be done with an image texture mapped to UV coordinates, or even another procedural texture....

Comment: So you want to overlay two textures onto one object, and displace one texture to only show for some parts of your object? This can be done with a mask if you want it to be dynamic, or you can select individual faces your 2nd texture will apply to

Comment: Craig D Jones,  FreemoX, I'm not familiar with this vocabulary that much. Do I need to unwrap the model for vertex paint?    FreemoX, how to add the mask ?

Comment: Always a good idea to unwrap. But if I've understood you correctly, why not just go to Photoshop or your preferred image manipulation software and edit your texture to contain your 2nd texture? Depending on your mesh, this can be a very time saving and easy way of doing it.

Comment: Could you suggest me tutorial for this? I don't know anything 2D.